# DDD principles and repositories with Dapper

Tags: c#, architecture, domain-driven-design, dapper

I'm setting up a solution in which I apply onion architecture and DDD patterns.

One of the DDD principles encourages domain entities to have only private setters and a private default constructor, to make sure you cannot create domain entities in an invalid state.

Repositories contain the data operations on domain entities, which are mapped from/to the database. I have been trying the following two approaches:

1. Domain entities in a purist way: no default constructor, no public setters; validation is done in the constructor(s); which makes sure you cannot create a domain entity in an invalid state. The side effect is that it's harder to dematerialize them in the repositories in read operations; as you need reflection in order to be able to create instances and map properties; and the use of dynamics in the Dapper requests which need to be mapped to the actual domain entities. If I would map this directly to the domain entities without the use of dynamics, *Dapper throws an exception that there is no public constructor*.
2. Domain entities in a non-purist way: you allow a default constructor, and all setters are public; so you can create entities that are not valid at a given point in time. In that case you need to call the Validate() method manually, to make sure they are valid before you continue. This makes dematerilizing in the repositories much easier, as you don't need reflection nor dynamics to map the database to the model.

Both methods work, however, with option 2 the repositories become a lot simpler because they contain a lot less custom mapping code, and without reflection obviously will be more performant as well. Of course, DDD is not applied in a purist way.

Before a decide what I will use in my project, a question: are there any other **micro-ORM frameworks** out there that can handle private constructors and setters, so that mapping the database to those kind of 'pure' domain entities is supported without additional custom mapping logic? (No EF nor NHibernate, I want something lightweight).

Or other technial solutions to keep the 'pure' model entity approach in combination with easy repository mapping?

EDIT: the solution I implemented was the following.

First, constructors and setters in the domain entities are all 'internal', which means they cannot be set by the consumers of the domain model. However, I use 'InternalsVisibleTo' to allow the data access layer to access them directly, so this means that dematerializing from the database is very easy with Dapper (no need for intermediate models). From the application layer, I can only use domain methods to change the domain entity, not the properties directly.

Second, to construct new domein entities from my application layer, I added fluent builders to help building domain entities, so I can now construct them like:

```
 User user = new UserBuilder()
        .WithSubjectId("045454857451245")
        .WithDisplayName("Bobby Vinton")
        .WithLinkedAccount("Facebook", la => la.WithProviderSubjectId("1548787788877").WithEmailAddress("bobby1@gmail.com"))
        .WithLinkedAccount("Microsoft", la => la.WithProviderSubjectId("54546545646").WithEmailAddress("bobby2@gmail.com"))
```

When the builder 'builds' the entity, validation is done as well, so you can never create an entity in an invalid state.

Comment: *What would you choose and why?*, *Are there any other...?*  [Are not valid questions on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow/tour)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> One of the DDD principles encourages domain entities to have only private setters and a private default constructor, to make sure you cannot create domain entities in an invalid state.

That's not quite right.  Yes, rich domain models don't usually expose setters, but that is because they don't *need* setters.  You tell the model what to do at a higher level of abstraction, and allow it to determine how its own data structures should be modified.

Similarly, there are *often* cases where it makes sense to expose the default constructor: if you think of an aggregate as a finite state machine, then the default constructor is a way to initialize the aggregate in its "start" state.

So normally you reconstitute an aggregate in one of two ways: either you initialize it in its default state, and then send it a bunch of messages, or you use the `Factory` pattern, as described in the blue book.

> this means an extra mapping in between, which makes code more complex

Perhaps, but it also ensures that your domain code is less dependent on ORM magic.  In particular, it means that your domain logic can be operating on a *different* data structure than what is used to make persistence "easy".

But it isn't free -- you have to describe in code how to get values out of the aggregate root and back into the database (or into the ORM entity, acting as a proxy for the database).

Comment: In the meanwhile I came to an approach, and I think it matches with what you just said: 1) creating domain entities in the application layer will be done with fluent builders, which create the entities and apply validation using the specific fluent validator. Those builders produce valid entities, in the Build() method. 2) dematerializing domain entities is done by instantiating the entity and mapping the properties directly through Dapper. In a lot of cases the domain entity matches the dabatase structure, in case it doesn't, dynamics will be used and mapped manually to the domain entities.

Comment: @L-Four "1) creating domain entities in the application layer will be done with fluent builders, which create the entities and apply validation using the specific fluent validator. Those builders produce valid entities, in the Build() method." - Why do you need this over engineering nightmare???

Comment: @DmitriBodiu I added an example to my question. As you see, it's very easy, and I don't nee any nightmare or over engineering, only applying standard patterns :)

Comment: @L-Four I don't see any value in it. You can have a simple ctor on your model. Could you share your User model and UserBuilder implementation?

Comment: If you would use a constructor, then you end up with a lot of parameters because it should contain all mandatory parameters. Constructor also don't explicitly show business intend by looking at it. So those builders are simply helpers to construct the domain entity. Also, in my case, it's not only building a user (aggregate root) , but also aggregates that are not aggregate root (linked account), so a more complex entity. Here it's explained: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/software-development/design/three-reasons-why-i-like-the-builder-pattern/

Answer (score 3):

The key is that you don't use Dapper to work with your domain entities, but instead you use it inside your repository layer with POCO entities. Your repository methods will return Domain entities by converting the POCO entities (that Dapper uses for data access) to Domain entities.

Comment: Yes, that is option 1 that I described (dynamics are the POCO entities). But this means an extra mapping in between, which makes code more complex.

Comment: mapping code is never complex whereas coupling your domain logic or entity design to data access concerns is a sure way to bring unneeded complexity and rigidity to your domain.

Comment: Well actually I noticed that mapping, for example, users, was double the code if I custom mapped it, so in most cases it is easier. In the other cases, if domain entities don't match the database exactly or I need custom mapping for some reason I will indeed use dynamics with Dapper en map those to the domain model. Thanks!